# How Java manage following scenario?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I tried some code to justify the reliability of synchronized block locking mechanism. Consider my sample code

My clocking object.

```
public class MyLock {
final static Object lock=new Object();
}
```

Class with synchronized blocks

```
public class Sample {

public void a(String input) {
    System.out.println(input+" method a");
    synchronized (lock) {
        System.out.println("inside synchronized block in a");
        try {
            System.out.println("waiting in a");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("calling b() from a");
            new Sample().b("call from a");
            System.out.println("waiting again in a");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("Running again a");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void b(String input) {
    System.out.println(input+" method b");
    synchronized (lock) {
        System.out.println("bbb " + input);
    }
 }

}
```

Test1 class

```
public class Test1 implements Runnable{

public static void main(String[] args) {
   new Thread(new Test1()).start();
   new Thread(new Test2()).start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
   new Sample().a("call from main");
 }
}
```

Test2 class

```
public class Test2 implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {
   new Sample().b("call from main");
 }
}
```

I just did this because I thought there will be a dead lock scenario if same thread witch holding the lock is going to access another method witch locked using same lock. Now consider the out put

```
call from main method a
call from main method b
inside synchronized block in a
waiting in a
calling b() from a // i thought this will cause a dead lock
call from a method b
bbb call from a
waiting again in a
Running again a
bbb call from main
```

Now you can see there is no such issue. My question is how `Java` manage this situation?

Answer (score 6):

### `synchronized` block is Reentrant

By default the lock (*mutex to be precise*) used in `synchronized` block is *[Reentrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex)*, which means if the same thread tries to acquire the same lock again it will not have to wait and will immediately enter the critical block as it already owns that lock.

### Where is Reentrancy useful?

Simple answer is ***Recursion***.

Consider the scenario of recursion on a `synchronized` method,

```
int synchronized method(int param){
   //... some logic

   method(param - 1);
}
```

In this example you would not want the same thread to be blocked for the same lock, as it will never be able to proceed.

Deadlock occurs in this scenario:

```
Thread A acquires lock A
Thread B acquires lock B
Thread A tries to acquire lock B
Thread B tries to acquire lock A
```

Now in this situation no one will be able to proceed and hence deadlock. But in your scenario there is only one lock, so the other thread will just wait for the first thread to leave the lock and then continue.

Answer (score 0):

Since your lock object is static it is shared among threads. Once thread A has acquired the lock, and when thread B enters method B of sample class it tries to acquire the same lock Which is owned by thread A. So there is no chance of deadlock.

Problem could have been where thread A tries to acuire the lock it already holds in method B, but this hasnt happened in your case as synchnorized block itself is reenterant but if you would have implemented your own lock class and if you wouldnt have cjecked for renterency, there would have been a dead lock.